# How can I use literal DOM markup as a Prototype Template?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, prototype, templates

Prototype's [Template](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/template) class allows you to easily substitute values into a string template.  Instead of declaring the Template source-string in my code, I want to extract the source-string from the DOM.

For example, in my markup I have an element:

```
<div id="template1">
  <img src="#{src}" title="#{title}" />
</div>
```

I want to create the template with the inner contents of the div element, so I've tried something like this:

```
var template = new Template($('template1').innerHTML);
```

The issue is that Internet Explorer's representation of the innerHTML omits the quotes around the attribute value when the value has no spaces.  I've also attempted to use `Element#inspect`, but in Internet Explorer I get back a non-recursive representation of the element / sub-tree.

Is there another way to get a Template-friendly representation of the sub-tree's contents?

Comment: Doesn't the browser kind of choke on the invalid URL in the `src` property of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resig to the rescue:](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)

> You can also inline script:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/html" id="user_tmpl">
>   <% for ( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) { %>
>     <li><a href="<%=users[i].url%>"><%=users[i].name%></a></li>
>   <% } %>
> </script>
> ```
>
> Quick tip: Embedding scripts in your
>   page that have a unknown content-type
>   (such is the case here - the browser
>   doesn't know how to execute a
>   text/html script) are simply ignored
>   by the browser - and by search engines
>   and screenreaders. It's a perfect
>   cloaking device for sneaking templates
>   into your page. I like to use this
>   technique for quick-and-dirty cases
>   where I just need a little template or
>   two on the page and want something
>   light and fast.
>
> and you would use it from script like
>   so:
>
> ```
> var results = document.getElementById("results");
> results.innerHTML = tmpl("item_tmpl", dataObject);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can embed the template source inside a `textarea` tag instead of a `div` and retrieve it using `Element#value`.

Certainly makes the markup a little weird, but it still seems reasonably-friendly to designers.

Additionally, as Jason pointed out in a comment to the original question, including the `img` tag in the textarea prevents a spurious request for an invalid image.